# Count people by gender

Tags: c#, xml

I need some help with C# and XML.

I'm building a web application and need to present information about number of peope with gender Male in a specific department (How many men in Dep1).

This is my XML file:

```
<company>
  <department>
    <departmentname>Dep 1</departmentname>
    <people>
      <person>
        <name>Sean</name>
        <date>2013-10-10</date>
        <gender>male</gender>
        <age>40</age>
      </person>
      <person>
        <name>John</name>
        <date>2013-10-18</date>
        <gender>male</gender>
        <age>45</age>
      </person>
      <person>
        <name>Linda</name>
        <date>2013-09-10</date>
        <gender>female</gender>
        <age>42</age>
      </person>
      <person>
        <name>Bob</name>
        <date>2013-10-01</date>
        <gender>male</gender>
        <age>35</age>
      </person>
    </people>
  </department>
  <department>
    <departmentname>Dep 2</departmentname>
    <people>
      <person>
        <name>Art</name>
        <date>2013-09-10</date>
        <gender>male</gender>
        <age>38</age>
      </person>
      <person>
        <name>Christina</name>
        <date>2013-10-20</date>
        <gender>female</gender>
        <age>45</age>
      </person>
      <person>
        <name>Marie</name>
        <date>2013-09-10</date>
        <gender>female</gender>
        <age>49</age>
      </person>
    </people>
  </department>
</company>
```

My code (not finished and not working):

```
XElement company= XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("myXML.xml"));

XElement department= (from p in company.Elements("department")
                     where p.Element("departmentname").Value == 'Dep 1' && p.Element 
                     ("gender").Value == 'male'
                    select p).Count;  

numberTextBox.Text = department.Element; //???How to write to textbox
```

Comment: `kon` should be `gender`. You have no "kon" tag.

Comment: Where's kon tag in you XML?

Comment: Yes, sorry bad translation. I have changed kon to gender in the code above. The code and XML is in reality much longer (and in a different language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's separate out some of the elements of the search to make it easier to follow:

```
XElement depName = company.Descendants("departmentname")
                          .Where(x => x.Value == "Dep 1")
                          .FirstOrDefault();

XElement[] men = depName.Parent.Descendants("gender")
                        .Where(x => x.Value == "male")
                        .Where(x => (int)x.Parent.Element("age") > 40)
                        .ToArray();

int count = men.Length;
```

`depName.Parent` is the department element.  From that we get all the gender's with the value `male`.  So the variable `men` is only the genders.  If you want the whole `person` element, use the men's `Parent` property to get that.  For example:

```
foreach(XElement man in men)
    Console.Writeline(man.Parent.Element("name").Value);
```

To assign to the textbox:

```
numberTextBox.Text = count.ToString(); // or men.Length.ToString()
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. The code (translated into my own) works perfectly! How would I write if I also want to take into account that the men have to be over 40 years old? I mean if I want to select all the men from Dep 1 with an age of over 40.
It won't work for me when I try to use the > sign. Is there Another way of doing it?

Comment: @user2939293 I edited the `men =` to include the additional age 40 request.  You can cast the XElement to basic types like int, double, string, DateTime, etc (if it makes sense of course).

Answer (score 2):

```
var department = (from p in company.Elements("department")
                 where p.Element("departmentname").Value == "Dep 1" && p.Element 
                 ("gender").Value == "male"
                select p).Count();
```

You're not retrieving an XElement, you're retrieving an `int` (which is what `Count` returns).
Using `var` will infer this for you.

And per my comment: `kon` -> `gender`.

Comment: Why not just `company.Elements("department").Count(p=>p.Element("departmentname").Value == "Dep 1" && p.Element("gender").Value == "male")`?

Comment: Also `'male'` should be `"male"`, and `'Dep 1'` should be `"Dep 1"`

Comment: @大师燈XiHuan: good catch, I've changed the accents. Sure this could be rewritten more tidy but in the end this will return pretty much the same IL code after all. It's a matter of preference how he likes to write his LINQ.

Comment: Jeroen, I tried your suggestion but got the error message
"Cannot assign method Group to an implicitly-typed local variable".
It seems it does not work with "var"

!Thank you for your help! I appreciate it (and I'm a female :-)

Comment: @user2939293: does it help when you change `var` to `int`?

Comment: @user2939293: the method is `Count()`, there's no property `Count`.

Comment: I Think the problem is that "gender" is too Deep into the root system. 
Somehow I have to get to the node "Gender" and I don't Think I am doing i the right way. Just don't know how to...

Comment: It also says that I am not allowed to use &&

Comment: -1 You can't simply copy his code and change `''` to `""` and `Count` to `Count()` and add the `var` and expect it to work.  His code is not going to work as is.  For example, `p` doesn't contain a child element `gender`.  There are multiple `gender` descendants of `p`, but none are direct children of `p`.

Comment: (-1 continued) His code currently (if it worked) would get all departments with the name `Dep 1` and have a male in it, and count them (the departments).  The max it could be (unless there were multiple departments with the same name) would be `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you..

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(your document);
var items = doc.GetElementsByTagName("gender");
var x=items.Count;
int malecount=doc.SelectNodes("gender[. = \"male\"]").Count;
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it later, have to go away for a while.

Comment: Your code doesn't take into account that the departmentname must be Dep 1

Answer (score 0):

You could try just XMLDocument and Xpath, just use the following code

```
        var xpath = "/company/department[departmentname='Dep 1']/people/person[/company/department/people/person/gender='male']/name";
        var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load("company.xml");
        var result = xmldoc.SelectNodes(xpath);
        if (result != null) Assert.AreEqual(4,result.Count);
```

Hope this helps.